# NumberFormatException when attempting to parse string as an integer

Tags: java, string, parseint

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 400"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
        at Library.loadBooks(Library.java:191)
        at UseLibrary.main(UseLibrary.java:102)
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Where is the code that causes this error?

Comment: This error doesn't have anything to do with File IO.  The hint is in the fact there is nothing to do with io in the stack trace.

Answer (score 13):

You have a whitespace in `" 400"` that is resulting in a `NumberFormatException`.

Just use `String.trim()` before trying to parse.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) for more information on `String.trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use .trim() function to eliminate spaces.

```
Integer.valueOf(" 400".trim());
```

That function would avoid you this kind of problems.