# Attempt to parseInt from a String throws "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, textfield, parseint

I'm attempting to accept 5 numbers in a textField from the user, in order to sort them using different methods (bubbleSort, mergeSort, quickSort). Unfortunately, I keep having "java.lang.NullPointerException" thrown. I've looked around a bit, and the closest I could find to my issue is [NumberFormatException when attempting to parse string as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085144/numberformatexception-when-attempting-to-parse-string-as-an-integer), but that was simply due to an empty space. I threw in a .trim() just for good measure though, to no avail.

```
public class SortWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textFieldInput;

    private String[] list;
    private int[] numList;

    private static JTextArea textAreaOutput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SortWindow window = new SortWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public SortWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        //Buttons

        JButton buttonBubble = new JButton("Bubble");
        buttonBubble.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textAreaOutput.setText("");
                list = textFieldInput.getText().split(" ");
                numList[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[0].trim());
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                    numList[i] = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
                }
                bubbleSort(numList);
            }
        });
        buttonBubble.setBounds(12, 13, 115, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonBubble);

        //Text Fields

        textFieldInput = new JTextField(5);
        textFieldInput.setBounds(177, 13, 243, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldInput);
        textFieldInput.setColumns(10);

        textAreaOutput = new JTextArea();
        textAreaOutput.setLineWrap(true);
        textAreaOutput.setText("In the box above, enter 5 numbers separated by spaces.");
        textAreaOutput.setEditable(false);
        textAreaOutput.setBounds(177, 66, 243, 176);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textAreaOutput);
    }
}
```

list is an array of Strings, and when I enter 1 2 3 4 5 (or any other combination - I even tried just entering a single digit and seeing what happened using my second line, but it still threw the exception) into the textField in my GUI, it stores it correctly within the String array, and I can successfully print the individual Strings within it perfectly fine using System.out.print(). My problem only arises when I attempt to use any of the following four lines (I only included the second line to make sure there wasn't something wrong with my for loop).

I can provide the rest of my code if needed, but I figured I'd start with this, since I can't think of anything else that would be affecting it.

EDIT: Added a much larger part of my class to the OP. The exception is thrown in line 60, which is:

```
numList[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[0].trim());
```

EDIT2: As requested, this is what I am given.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SortWindow$2.actionPerformed(SortWindow.java:60)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you write your entire error code line? What line number does it fail at - is it at the `numList[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[0].trim());`? It would also help if you could share a bit more of your class.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that all that code is commented out.

Comment: Yes, it is at the part you mentioned. Or the for loop if I attempt to only use it. Going to edit my OP to include all parts of my class that are relevant in some manner.

Comment: @Hot Licks - it's only commented out to show where my errors are. Sorry if that was misleading.

Comment: OP has been updated. I also removed the comments from my error lines.

Comment: So, where do you initialise `numList` ? I still can't see it.  I can see you trying to set the entries in `numList`, but not `numList` itself.  You want `numList = new int[list.length];` before you start using it.

Comment: Right - user Rafa El pointed out the same thing below. An embarassing oversight on my part >.<

Thanks for looking out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your numList size might not been initialized. you can try like this and see if its okay:

```
int[] numList=new int[5];
    String[] list =  textFieldInput.getText().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                 numList[i] = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
              }
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numList));
```

Comment: Well now I feel silly - adding =new int[5] did it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That Exception means that the Item in your list is Empty (has value of null), check your list items the problem is there, and not in the parsing part! 
try :

```
   System.out.println(list[0]);
```

and watch the output.

Comment: Entering "1" (or 1 2 3... etc for that matter) into my textField and then printing list[0] prints 1, with no errors.

Comment: try split("\\s") instead of split(" ") / or split("\\s+") if you want to get ride of extra spaces..

Comment: Turns out my issue was my overlooking of something small. I will try what you just added though. Thanks.